# JQM dynamic popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a form in which on clicking submit button the form data is sent through ajax and the related message may it be error or confirmation details from the server script which has been written in php is displayed . For now every thing is working fine . But what I want to know is that the message whcih is being displayed with help of JS can I change it into JQM popup as I am using JQM 1.4.2 for my design .

**Popup**

```
<div data-role="popup" id="mDialog" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="c" style="max-width:400px;" class="ui-corner-all">
                <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-top">
                  <h1>Attention!!</h1>
                </div>
                <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">
                  <h3 class="ui-title">{Are you sure you want to delete this page?</h3>
                  <p>This action cannot be undone.}  <?php if($this->error->description!='')echo trim($this->error->description)?> </p>
                  <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-theme="c">Cancel</a>    
                  <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow" data-theme="b">Delete</a>  
                </div>
            </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

Put this in your HTML, above your `<form>`

```
<div id="formNotice"><img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading" /></div>
```

Now put this where you handle the AJAX response

```
$("#formNotice").html(AJAXResponse);
$("#formNotice").popup("open");
```

Here's the [docs](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0-rc.2/docs/pages/popup/index.html?user=&pass=)

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R8n84/) (Without JQM - but you get the idea)

Comment: and what should I do to add a loading image before the error is shown ??

Comment: Thanks bro I have been doing something like this in my desktop version was loading an image with Jquery when you click submit . Also I was trying to make this popup look like a page is it possible with two buttons to go back or delete.. I am getting an error man in script   
Error: cannot call methods on popup prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "go back or delete" :/

Comment: updated my question with the script and the error was coming because I did not initialize the div as popup was solved using      $("#mDialog").popup();
 $("#mDialog").popup("open");